# In VS Code: How to open a file in the workspace by search for its name

Tags: visual-studio-code, filenames

In my VS Code workspace I want to open a file by its name.

For example my workspace <s>is a directory with</s> *has a few directories with each*, say, a couple of hundred files and I look for a file with the name:

```
mycompanyname_abc_def.hs
```

Many files start with `mycompanyname` but only this file contains `abc` in its filename. So preferably I'd like to find the file by just typing `abc`.

I know about Ctrl-P and Ctrl-R. They find the file if I have opened it before or *if the file is in the workspace's top folder*, but is there a command like Ctrl-P that finds *any* file in the workspace *even if it is in a subfolder*?

If VS Code doesn't have this out of the box, do any extensions exist providing this type of search/opening behaviour?

---

PS: Of course there is the normal system open dialog via Ctrl-O, but in my case (Barebone RHEL Linux) the Open Dialog does not provide any search functionality, only "select by click".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ctrl-P` - go to file - and type a part of the filename. Note that I don't find this excludes files that I haven't opened before - all files in my workspace are searchable.

For instance, if your file name is `mycompanyname_abc_def.hs` then `abc` or `myabc` should both work.

I am trying out the new (?) command center features as of version 1.73 and that is a good way to discover these types of navigation/search features:
[v1_73#_command-center-mode-shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_73#_command-center-mode-shortcuts)

Comment: This definitely doesn't work for me. However, I checked the structure of my workspace _and the file I look for is in a sub folder_. I have adjusted the question accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. Files in subfolders are searchable with ctrl-p for me.